# Hibernate many to many

Tags: hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and facing a few issues with many to many mapping.
Here is the scenario:
Table 1 contains Emp_id,first name(Emp_id is primary).
Table 2 contains Doc_id,doc name(Doc_id is primary)

Table 3 should have(Emp_id,Doc_id).This combination is the primary key over there and a many to many mapping has been established.

Consider both table 1 and 2 as static.I would like to insert record into the 3rd table using many to many  but the first two tables should be untouched.

Please help with this.Thanks!

Comment: Please, add your persistent classes. It is more simply to work with a code than with a natural language description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't interact with Table 3 directly.  Hibernate will manage it for you once you declare the many-to-many relationship.

E.g.

Emp.java

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
  name="TABLE_3"
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="Emp_Id")
  inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="Doc_Id")
)
public Set<Doc> getDocs() {
  return this.docs;
}
```

When you add an existing Doc object to Emp.docs and persist Emp, the only affect will be to add a row to TABLE_3.

Comment: Thanks,I found the solution in some other way.